# Shopify, bulk operations and metaobjects

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to run a bulk query on Shopify, leveraring **bulkOperationRunQuery**:

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/mutations/bulkOperationRunQuery

My problem is that I want to query **metaobjects**, and I don't find how to use bulkOperationRunQuery with such queries.

Here is below an example of a query I'd like to send in bulk, for instance if I try to get the identifier field of my 5000 cars:

```
query Metaobjects {
    metaobjects(type: "car") {
        nodes {
            field(key: "identifier") {
                key
                value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query works like that, but I don't know how to feed bulkOperationRunQuery with this query.

I followed this documentation, replacing the query example by mine, but can't make it work:
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries#write-a-bulk-operation

In fact, I wonder if bulkOperationRunQuery can accept metaobjects queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original

The `reference` needs to have subsection
`{ __typename }`

Bulk query must be able to run this. There isn't a hard-no for this type.

#### Updated after post update

Fine tuned the query to match the bulk query format. What I observed was it required `edges` and replaced the `nodes` with `node`.
Could you confirm me if this runs for you? My current store doesn't have permissions to query these.

```
mutation {
  bulkOperationRunQuery(
    query: """
        {
          metaobjects(type: "car") {
            edges {
              node {
                field(key: "identifier") {
                  key
                  value
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    """
  ) {
    bulkOperation {
      id
      status
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Successful run]
[image]
Here's a snapshot of Bulk request being created and its status. ( Yeah I know access is not there but this is my testing account. )

Comment: You're right, but the issue is not here with the bulk operation. I've fixed my initial post by removing the reference and type.

Comment: @Tom-Lunabee.com thanks for updating the post. I've updated my post to match yours and added my fix. I'm curious here. Please could you confirm on this? thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're correct, it works. I was missing the edges part of the query. Not sure why it is required, in fact 

Comment: Great ! Edges helps in defining the return type would be an array. Like bunch of nodes connected to parent node via edges ⽊